# Prove that a specific $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ element has order three using defining relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Consider the following element in $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$: $$X=T_{31}^{-k}T_{13}^2T_{31}^{-m}T_{13}^{-m-1}T_{31}^{2}T_{13}^{-n}T_{31}^{-4m^2-3}S_{13}^{-1}T_{23}^{2m^2+m+1-(4m^2+3)n}T_{21}^{k-n}S_{23}.$$
Here, the $T_{ij}$ are matrices with entries $1$ on the diagonal and entry $i,j$, while the rest of the entries are $0$.
For example, $$T_{12}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Furthermore, the $S_{ij}$ are defined in terms of the $T_{ij}$ as: $$S_{ij}=T_{ij}T_{ji}^{-1}T_{ij}.$$
Finally, $k,m,n$ are arbitrary integers.

It can be readily checked that this element has order three, i.e. $X^3=1$, for example in Mathematica. I want to prove this algebraically, making only use of the defining $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ relations: $$T_{ij}T_{kl}=T_{kl}T_{ij} \quad (i\neq l , j\neq k),\quad T_{ij}T_{jk}=T_{ik}T_{jk}T_{ij} \quad (i\neq k), \quad (T_{ij}T^{-1}_{ji}T_{ij})^4=1.$$
I believe a good strategy would be to first prove $X^2=X^{-1}$, which could possibly be achieved by commuting the $T_{23}$ and $S_{23}$ factors in $X^2$ to the left.
However, after quite a bit of experimentation I have not succeeded to prove $X^3=1$.

My question is: how does one prove algebraically that $X^3=1$? And: is there perhaps a better representation of $X$ into generators that makes the proof easier to see?

Comment: It is a matter of considering the exponents from the relations, so again a calculation like mathematica does. Try an example by hand for fixed $m,k,n$ to see what happens.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  I am not entirely sure if I understand what you mean. I have been using the relations to try and simplify $X^2$ for general $k,m,n$. It is important for my purpose to know exactly which of the basic relations have been used. I agree that it is probly useful to work it out for a specific example of fixed $k,m,n$, which I will try. Thank you for your comment.